# Keras get the output of the last layer during training

Tags: keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

The goal is to recover the output of the last layer of the variational auto-encoder in the training phase for use as training data for another algorithm.
Attached is the model variational autoencoder code:

```
encoding_dim=58
input_dim=xtrain.shape[1]
inputArray=Input(shape=(input_dim,))
encoded= Dense(units=encoding_dim,activation="tanh")(inputArray) 
encoded= Dense(units=29,activation="tanh")(encoded)
encoded= Dense(units=15,activation="tanh")(encoded)
encoded= Dense(units=10,activation="tanh")(encoded)
encoded= Dense(units=3,activation="tanh")(encoded)
encoded= Dense(units=10,activation="tanh")(encoded)
decoded= Dense(units=15,activation="tanh")(encoded)
decoded= Dense(units=29,activation="tanh")(decoded)
decoded= Dense(units=encoding_dim,activation="tanh")(decoded)
decoded= Dense(units=input_dim,activation="sigmoid")(decoded) 
autoecoder=Model(inputArray,decoded)
autoecoder.summary()

autoecoder.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(),loss="mean_squared_error",metrics=["mae"])
#hyperparametrs :
batchsize=100
epoch=10
history = autoecoder.fit(xtrain_noise,xtrain,
              batch_size=batchsize,
              epochs=epoch,
              verbose=1,
              shuffle=True,
              validation_data=(xtest_noise,xtest),
              callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir="../logs/DenoiseautoencoderHoussem")])
```

I have found that I can retrieve the desired layer as follows:

```
autoecoder.layers[10].output
```

but how do I store his output during training in a list? Thanks.

**Edit:**
I can do this by use the prediction method of the model on the xtrain data, but I think this is not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can train a new model using the predictions of a previously trained model simply stacking on the desired output new layers and set trainable = False on the old layer. Here a dummy example

```
# after autoencoder fitting

for i,l in enumerate(autoecoder.layers):
    autoecoder.layers[i].trainable = False
    print(l.name, l.trainable)

output_autoecoder = autoecoder.layers[10].output
x_new = Dense(32, activation='relu')(output_autoecoder) # add a new layer for exemple

new_model = Model(autoecoder.input, x_new)
new_model.compile('adam', 'mse')
new_model.summary()
```

I use the output of the last autoencoder layer as the input of new blocks. We can merge all compiling a new model where the inputs are the same as autoecoder, in this way we can use the training data for another algorithm without calling the prediction method

Comment: Thanks @marco, its a good solution if I try to use the output of the auto encoder as input for another DL algorithm, but in my case, the output will be the training dataset of xgboost

Comment: In this way, the predict method is the only solution available... If you consider this answer valuable don't forget to accept it as answer or upvote

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, the only solution that can be used is the .predict method of DL model. thank you @marrco